# Where can I find the measured magnetic moments of the quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, quarks, magnetic-moment

I read that the magnetic moment of the proton can be expressed as the sum of the magnetic moments of the three quarks like $\mu_p = \frac{4}{3}\mu_u - \frac{1}{3}\mu_d$. But I couldn't find a table listing the measured magnetic moments of the quarks. Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: The magnetic moments of the nucleons are largely *not* the sum of the magnetic moments of the valence quarks in any microscopic model (the "constituent quark model" that Johannes talks about is a crude tool long since abandoned for most purposes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a quark $q_i$ is a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ Dirac particle with charge $z_i e$ and constituent mass $m_i$ with $i=u,d,s...$ theory predicts its magnetic moment as

$ \mu_i = \frac{z_i e \hbar}{2 m_i}$.

Note that the formula in your question is only valid in the constituent quark model where a baryon consists only of three constituent quarks. Therefore you have to use the constituent quark mass in the formula for the magnetic moment too. A list of constituent quark masses is eg. found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_quark). These masses are obtained from hadron spectroscopy.

I am not aware of any direct measurements of quark magnetic moments.

Comment: Is $z_i = \pm 1/3,\pm 2/3$ ? What about the $g$-factor for the different quarks?

Comment: Yes it is. The $g$-factor in this model is 2 for all quarks, because they are considered point particles with spin 1/2 obeying the Dirac equation (no QED).

Comment: Can you point me to a reference describing the constituent quark model, where the equations for the magnetic moment according to this model are explained?

Comment: You can read about this in just about every introductory particle physics book. For example the books of [Griffiths](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Elementary-Particles-David-Griffiths/dp/3527406018/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (chapter 5.10) and [Povh](http://www.amazon.com/Particles-Nuclei-Introduction-Physical-Concepts/dp/3540793674/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1302791571&sr=1-1) (chapter 15.4) cover it.

Answer (score 3):

Quarks are confined.

Any "measurements" come from the measurements of seen particles, utilizing  the Dirac equation, Quantum Field Theory  and the symmetries of the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_model)  to constrain the quantities of the quarks, be it masses or moments or charges.

The standard model was extremely well verified by the measurements at [LEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEP) up to the energies of LEP.