# Isn't the spin only a synonym for the existence of a magnetic dipole moment and its direction?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

For this question [What does the magnetic moment of a quantum particle depend on?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320649/)  was given such statement:

> The magnetic moment of ... an electron, is intrinsic, and related to spin.

Isn't the spin only a synonym for the existence of a magnetic dipole moment and its direction?

Comment: *"Isn't the spin only a synonym for the existence of a magnetic dipole moment and its direction?"*...why would you think it is?

Comment: @ACuriousMind give please an example of phenomena where the magnetic dipole moment couldn't exchanged by spin.

Comment: @Holger that's completely backwards - to disapprove the assertion in the OP what you need is a phenomenon where the spin cannot be exchanged for a magnetic moment, of which there are plenty.

Comment: Spin contributes to the centrifugal force in hydrogen atoms. It is a mechanical effect. See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370298/

Answer (score 4):

No. The spin of quantum particles is indeed an angular momentum, and it can be changed over into orbital angular momentum if the circumstances are right. The [Einstein-de Haas effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect) is the canonical example of this.

Comment: Spin also has *profound* physical effects not associated with magnetic fields. You know, little things like the periodic table and other important features of chemistry; and the behavior of solids.